# encounter this 'IndexError: list index out of range' error while i fetch image name and split with ',' .

Tags: python, split

currently started playing with kggle data set DOGVSCATE image classification, this is my code for training data for image classification.
how can i solve this problem,  - > [-3] at this position dog or cate label available, so why indexError accure?

```
def label_img(img):
    word_lable = img.split('.')[-3]
    #print(word_lable)
    if word_lable == 'cat':
        return [1,0]
    elif word_lable == 'dog': 
        return [0,1]
def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
         label = label_img(img)
         path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)
         img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE),(IMGSIZE,IMGSIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img), np.array(label)])
    shuffle(training_data)
    np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
    return training_data

train_data = create_train_data()
```

and error look like this

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-14532aaf4afc> in <module>()
 ----> 1 train_data = create_train_data()
       2 # train_data = np.load('train_data.npy')

<ipython-input-66-d482278d7b47> in create_train_data()
      2     training_data = []
      3     for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
----> 4         label = label_img(img)
      5         path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR,img)
      6         img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), (IMGSIZE,IMGSIZE))

<ipython-input-65-daea6f12c9a3> in label_img(img)
      1 def label_img(img):
----> 2     word_lable = img.split('.')[-3]
      3     #print(word_lable)
      4     if word_lable == 'cat':
      5         return [1,0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please have a look on [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We currently can't help since we have no idea what `img` looks like... All we can say is that `img` seems to have its first dimension smaller than 3.

Comment: cat.1.jpg e.g or my image name, as u see img name contains two dots, so according to python documentation split()[-3] returns dog value that what i need,

Comment: Can you `print img` right before your `split('.')[-3]` please? Since `s = 'cat.1.jpg' ; print s.split('.')[-3]` returns `cat`. If you have a problem, this means that `img` is not equal to `cat.1.jpg` as you claim.

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess will be that *img* contains less than 2 dots (maybe, even none), thus producing less than 3 elements after split.
You may check the length of the list produced by *split* before taking third element form the end.

**EDIT:**

```
In [5]: 'dog.11.jpg'.split('.')[-3]
Out[5]: 'dog'
```

Works like charm. There ate other files in your directory that fail this code. Use try/except

Comment: ya already tried, img contains 2 dots , eg. dog.11.jpg , something like that, and i need 'dog' from split,